# How quickly can 2 iphones exchange information regarding tilt/position?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, information-retrieval

I was wondering what amount of time is required to convey information regarding the tilt and position (not gps) of one particular iphone to another. Could 2 iphones send and receive this information simultaneously? What about 3 iphones? I'm interested in an application that is able to simultaneously send and receive and make conditional decisions based on this information received all within a half a second-ish.

Any shot this is possible? If so, is bluetooth or wifi better?

Thanks a ton,
Jake

Comment: I don't have any sort of answer to your question, but the first thing that came to mind when reading it was: iPhone lightsaber.

Answer (score 4):

This is currently not possible without an intermediate server. (Without a jailbreak, which would make it possible, but extremely difficult)

I'm assuming your purpose is gaming, in which case, the latency associated with a trip to a server and back over a cellular data network, is likely to take too long for any satisfactory gaming experience. I don't believe it would be within half a second.

This will be possible via Bluetooth in the upcoming 3.0 iPhone software, but that is still under NDA, so you are not likely to be able to get any reliable performance numbers until it is released. If I were guessing, I would certainly guess that the latency associated with a direct Bluetooth connection would be FAR under half a second.

Comment: Great answer. Looking forward to OS3. 

I'm actually looking to have an application developed that isn't quite gaming. You're right that transferring position info over a network/server would definitely take too long for this concept to work. There is nothing that exists in the current OS that allows direct phone-to-phone communication via bluetooth without jailbreaking?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

All you've got as an option right now is Wi-Fi or the Cell Network. If you use Bonjour over Wi-Fi, you'd have latencies in the milliseconds, but all the phones would have to be connected to the same access point. Take a look at the WiTap example.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible, you'd want to connect your peers over WiFi for best performance and reliability, but Bluetooth would be ok as long as your data packets were constrained to small sizes (< 1k).  Check out this documentation and sample code to see how to access UIAccelerometer:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007410

The trick is that the update frequency is controlled in part by the systems needs, so there may be a window (while the system is attempting to update device orientation) wherein your application receives no updates.